# MvxFragment enter animation

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to implement enter and exit fragment animation during navigation in MVVMCross project.

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(TestViewModel), 
        Resource.Id.content_frame, true,
        Resource.Animation.enter_from_right,
        Resource.Animation.exit_nothing_animation)]
```

`enter_from_right`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

`exit_nothing_animation`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="1" />
```

I expect that new fragment slide from right over the old frgamnet and old fragment will remain in the same place.

But new fragment just instantly appears without animation

Other topics suggest use Add insted Replace, but what the right way in MVVMCross project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is override this method in base fragment class

```
public override Animation OnCreateAnimation(int transit, bool enter, int nextAnim)
        {
            if (nextAnim == Resource.Animation.enter_from_right)
            {
                ViewCompat.SetTranslationZ(view, 1f);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewCompat.SetTranslationZ(view, 0f);
            }


            return base.OnCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please accept your answer, it will help others who have simialr issue.